# Displaying 2 names in TextBox from Excel Sheet

Tags: vba, excel

Excel 2013. How to display 2 names in a TextBox, data is from Excel Sheet. 
I can display a single name based on the employee ID, however if I'd like to display 2 names, it won't work. I enable multiline in TextBox2.

[image]

Code so far:

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()

Dim mySheet As Worksheet    'declaring mySheet as the Worksheet...
Dim x
Dim i As Long
Dim str As String
Set mySheet = Sheets("Sheet1")

x = mySheet.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Value

For i = 2 To UBound(x, 1)
    If x(i, 2) = Val(ComboBox1.Value) Then
        If str = "" Then
            str = x(i, 1)
        Else
            str = str & vbNewLine & x(i, 1)
        End If
    End If
Next i

If str <> "" Then
    TextBox3.Value = str
Else
    TextBox3.Value = "Match not found"
End If

End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

ComboBox1.Clear

With ComboBox1
    .AddItem "Mon"
    .AddItem "Tue"
    .AddItem "Wed"
End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set Multilie property for TextBox3 to True and try the below code...

```
Private Sub TextBox1_Change()

Dim mySheet As Worksheet    'declaring mySheet as the Worksheet...
Dim x
Dim i As Long
Dim str As String
Set mySheet = Sheets("Sheet1")

x = mySheet.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Value

For i = 2 To UBound(x, 1)
    If x(i, 2) = Val(TextBox1.Value) Then
        If str = "" Then
            str = x(i, 1)
        Else
            str = str & vbNewLine & x(i, 1)
        End If
    End If
Next i

If str <> "" Then
    TextBox3.Value = str
Else
    TextBox3.Value = "Match not found"
End If

End Sub
```

If you have ComboBox1 instead of TextBox1 where ComboBox1 has text values, you can try it like this...

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
Dim mySheet As Worksheet    'declaring mySheet as the Worksheet...
Dim x
Dim i As Long
Dim str As String
Set mySheet = Sheets("Sheet1")

x = mySheet.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Value
If Application.CountIf(mySheet.Columns(2), ComboBox1.Value) > 0 Then
    For i = 2 To UBound(x, 1)
        If x(i, 2) = ComboBox1.Value Then
            If str = "" Then
                str = x(i, 1)
            Else
                str = str & vbNewLine & x(i, 1)
            End If
        End If
    Next i
    TextBox3.Value = str
Else
    TextBox3.Value = "Match not found"
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: sktneer thank you so much..it works now .that is really what I wanted to happen..I'm thinking of using a combobox with Mon, Tue, Wed...til Sun options using the .additem("") code. So that if I select Mon in combobox, all names with a day off of Monday will display in Textbox3..

Comment: yes it works..I'll update the code and this time I used ComBoBox1 and have 3 options..

Comment: Glad to know. :)

Comment: Thank you sktneer.. Can you help me fix if i'm using a ComBoBox..In my Excel sheet in column B I used data like Mon, Tue, Wed as pertaining to their Rest Days.  I have a combobox..If I choose Mon in ComBoBox1, I don't see the names of those people who has RD in Mon..Please help.

Comment: You need to change the IF statement to this... If x(i, 2) = ComboBox1.Value Then

Comment: I have edited the solution considering you are using a ComboBox.

Comment: I see ..I have to remove the Val section of the line. Thank you so much.  Is there a way to instead of using a TextBox for the display, I'm gonna use ListBox, because in TextBox you can't click on the text, I believe in Listbox you can click on the data inside..:-)

Comment: sktneer you already help me a lot and thank you so much..I owe you really something today. I will study your code and everything. The reason why I asked about this because I will use this to create a simple tool wherein I can use to know who's on RD on that specific day so that I know who to contact to.  Also I will try to include a command button so that I i select that employee or name, then click the button, I want to have an outlook with a ready template and send to that particular person. Thank you so much.

Comment: Is it okay to ask some help from you about this project sooner or later, if you're not really busy.?

Comment: You should open a new question if you have an issue in the current project. :)

Comment: Hi sktneer, I have a question ..it's on this link:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43792983/i-wanted-to-use-listbox-so-that-i-can-select-the-entry-rather-than-textbox

Answer (score 0):

Loop through the range and concatenate the values into the textbox like this:

```
If Not myRange Is Nothing Then
    For Each c In myRange.Cells
        TextBox3.Value =  TextBox3.Value & " " & c.Value
    Next
Else
    TextBox3.Value = "Match not found"
End If
```

Comment: Let me try that.  Thank you so much.

Comment: Sure. Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Hi I edit my code. When I type 111 I don't see the 2 names..But thank you so much though. I declare x as range.